# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

```
import urllib2
import html2text

print 'Please input URL with the text you want to analyze: '
url = raw_input()
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_content = page.read()
print html_content
rendered_content = html2text.html2text(html_content)
f = open('file_text.txt', 'w')
f.write(rendered_content)
f.close()
```

Was trying to save the file to my computer. I know there is a problem with the ASCII

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? Also, which python version do you use?

Comment: Don't forget to share what you are inputing in the `raw_input` call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: @omri_saadon I'm using version 2.7.12

Comment: @Bonifacio2 I was just using a random URL, like https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
html_content = page.read()
```

to

```
html_content = page.read().decode(errors='replace')
```

[str.decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode)